# graph api returns empty data for /me/groups - permissions are granted

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm querying /me/groups for all users to get the list of groups managed by the user. The app asks for `user_managed_groups` permission.

This API call works for every user. However, one user has reported a bug saying he is not getting any groups listed.

I tried to replicate the call with his access token and user_id from the app's database in Graph API Explorer and the result is empty `data`.

Again, I tried various other access tokens with their associated `user_id`s and they call are returning correct `data`.

So, I checked if the user who has reported the bug has granted us proper permissions (`user_managed_pages` among others) and turns out, he has granted.

I'm using Facebook's PHP SDK.
Let me know if you need more info.

I'm not allowed to upload images yet. And only 2 links are allowed. :(

So here is an album having all the images:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DghjQ.jpg)

**EDIT**

This may be relevant: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/806001356187097